# How do I add a break line to this object literal in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have a Column Component, and I'm trying to display these two data points with a break line, please help.

right now the result is:

BusinessName UserName

I'd like:

BusinessName

UserName

```
<Column
     calculateCellValue={(cellData: { BusinessName: string; UserName: string }) => 
     `${cellData.BusinessName} ${cellData.UserName}`}
/>
```

Comment: What does `Column` do with `calculateCellValue`?

Comment: it displays custom values, in my case it allows me to display 2 values vs just one @NicholasTower

Comment: `it displays custom values, in my case it allows me to display 2 values vs just one` That doesn't really answer my question. Can you show the code? Like, is it doing `<div>{calculateCellValue(someData)}</div>`? If you need `calculateCellValue` to return a string, that will change the set of possible solutions, compared to what you can do if returning a react element is ok. You've already gotten answers that suggest adding `"\n"` or `"<br/>"`, because people have made guesses about what you're doing with the calculateCellValue; guesses which turned out to be incorrect.

Comment: Seems like `<Column />` is an object that is used to render a column header. Wonder if one may use styling (ie, "CSS") on that element to display its contents one below the other.

Comment: calculate cell value returns an object @NicholasTower

Comment: `calculate cell value returns an object @NicholasTower` Not in the code you provided. You showed it returning a string, and i'm asking what `Column` does with that string. If it's returning an object, ok that's fine, but i'll still need to see what `Column` does with that object.

Answer (score -1):

`insert "\n"` :

```
<Column
     calculateCellValue={(cellData: { BusinessName: string; UserName: string }) => 
     `${cellData.BusinessName} +"\n" +${cellData.UserName}`}
/>
```

Comment: very original :))

Comment: doesn't work either

Comment: What `<Column/>` does?

Answer (score -1):

You should probably share the source code for the `Column` component as well, but see if this one works:

```
<Column
     calculateCellValue={(cellData: { BusinessName: string; UserName: string }) => 
     `${cellData.BusinessName}\n${cellData.UserName}`}
/>
```